# AppDelegate UIWindow addSubView in different viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwindow

I am trying to add a UILabel in UIWindow of AppDelegate from a UIViewController. This is how I am doing this:

**AppDelegate code** :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }



    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;


    return YES;
}
```

**ViewController code** :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UILabel *abcd=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 40.0)];

    abcd.text=@"loading...";

    abcd.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:abcd];

    [super viewDidLoad];


}
```

But all I am seeing is grey screen but no label. Where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Just a small tip, you do not have to check wether the app is running on an iPad to load a specific iPad or iPhone view. Just append the `~ipad` to the name of the view. Thus the iphone view file name will be: `ViewController.xib` and the iPad version will be: `ViewController~ipad.xib`. Now you can just load the view  with: `[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]` and iOS will load the correct one.

Comment: Oh...Thanks for the tip. :) Now the answer please. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I suggest you reverse the order of your last two delegate statements:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

2) While you should be able to add the label to the window, its somewhat unorthodox to do so. In any case, try adding the label to the viewController's view and see if that works, and if so, and you really want to add it to the window (for some reason), then add a comment here:

```
[self.view addSubview:abcd];
```

If you still cannot see the label its likely that there is an issue with the view controller. Did you define anything in the nib - any element that should be visible at launch ? If not then add something just so you can be sure the view is in fact getting loaded. [One trick I use is to set the background color of views to red or blue, so I can see that in fact they got loaded.]

Answer (score 3):

You must not add UILabel to UIWindow, you should add to UIViewController. Change this line:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:abcd];
```

for this:

```
[self.view addSubview:abcd];
```

Answer (score 2):

revers the order to

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then

try adding to the view first not to the window using following code

```
[self.view addSubview:abcd];
```

If this does not show your label then the view controller is not getting loaded.

If so then check the property of your xib file.

remove the window alloc line and check the hook up for your window in mainwindow.xib file if the hoockup is not correct then it will not load the view.

Comment: Thanks. The view controller is not getting loaded,so it does not show. Add code in **viewDidAppear**. Bold the line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your view controller's view is covering the one you added. Add the new view to the view controller's view instead:

```
[self.view addSubview:abcd];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after adding UILabel in UIWindow

```
  [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] makeKeyAndVisible];
```